# Question about paraphrasing this sentence in a less demanding and polite way

Tags: paraphrasing

How would you reword this:

> "Would you like to donate the children's foundation "Red
>   Nose"? It costs 1 dollar."

How can I let my customers at the pharmacy know they can donate more, for example, 5 dollars (or even more) so that they wouldn't feel ashamed even if they didn't like to participate?

Comment: What I've encountered is something along the lines of "Would you like to donate to the X Foundation? You can give as little as one dollar, and you'll get a red nose to show your generosity!" . . . I take it this is a bulbous clown nose?

Comment: @StoneyB That would make a good answer